# How to use tenary operator in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to do if else in react correctly? It managed to render the P tag but not the H tag. I am checking if the item.description is an empty string and if it is then returned H tag. Thanks

```
{this.state.onecoursedetail.map(item => (
                        <Fragment key={item.ID}>
                                <h3>{item.Title}</h3>

                               { item.Description === "" ?  <h1 style={{textAlign:'center'}}> Coming Soon..... </h1> : <p style={{fontSize:'1.2em', textAlign:'left'}}>{ReactHtmlParser(item.Description)}</p>
```

the SQL statement that returns the description item:

**coalesce([Description],'') as [Description]**

Comment: Did you close the curly braces?

Comment: Try logging out the values of item.Description to see if the blank ones are really just an empty string. I don't see anything wrong with your ternary.

Comment: Is there any error log in console?

Comment: Better still, `console.log(this.state.onecoursedetail)`

Comment: it returned null when I did console.log(item.Description). How should I comparison on null value? Thanks

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the reply. It was my mistake on my part, I called the wrong stored procedures. It works now. Thanks again for those replies

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing it correctly.

I think you lost a bracket there. Try this:

```
{this.state.onecoursedetail.map(item => (
                        <Fragment key={item.ID}>
                                <h3>{item.Title}</h3>

                               { item.Description === "" ?  <h1 style={{textAlign:'center'}}> Coming Soon..... </h1> : <p style={{fontSize:'1.2em', textAlign:'left'}}>{ReactHtmlParser(item.Description)}</p> }
```

Comment: sorry, I did have a bracket at the end but forgotten to place one in the question here. Thanks

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the reply. It was my mistake on my part, I called the wrong stored procedures. It works now. Thanks again for those replies